# clamtk does not work after update to latest gui

Tags: 14.04

After updating to newest version of clamtk I am unable to access all features like preferences, update and all others, but the gui opens and shows. How can I fix this to start using clamtk newest gui features on ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your [clamav](http://www.clamav.net/download.html) as well.  Click [here](http://www.clamav.net/download.html) to take you to the clamav download.  Go to the download folder that you downloaded it to, and type in the following from a terminal window:

```
tar zxvf clamav-0.98.7.tar.gz
```

then go to the folder that was just created

```
cd clamav-0.98.7/
```

Now, configure the source

```
./configure
```

Then `make` the source

```
sudo make
```

Then install the `clamav`

```
sudo make install
```

Hope this helps to get your `clamav` working with the new version of `clamtk`.

Comment: You know that ClamAV is available in the repositories too don't you?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda The one in the repositories does not work with ClamTK very well for some reason.  Especially the new version of ClamTK.  =(

Comment: Strange... They should be the same version...

Comment: In what way does it not work very well though?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda The source claims to be the same version.  Maybe it is the way it is installed.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I had clamav installed from the repository, and clamtk would not see the engine or the definitions, but when I ran the upgrades in clamtk it said it was fine.  But yet, clamtk still claimed it was wrong.  As soon as I downloaded the one from ClamAV and installed from source, it worked fine.

Comment: Odd, it works fine for me...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda That's good.  I don't normally use ClamTK because of that.  I prefer normal repositories, and just running the dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam for the definition updates.  I've never had any issues that way.  Plus, I do use Ubuntu 14.04, where you are 15.04, so the differences could be enough.

Comment: Yes, perhaps when you upgrade to the next LTS it will be all fixed in that one.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Maybe.  Next April we shall know.  =)