# ClamTK not working

Tags: malware, antivirus, clamtk

I think I have [this same issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683087/clamtk-does-not-work-after-update-to-latest-gui).
Lately, I noticed I get malware, that redirects me to fake websites while I browse. I installed `clamtk` and `clamav`, and it worked. But I recently updated eveything: the GUI seems nicer and there are more feature, but **it doesn't work**.

If I select a folder to be analyzed, an "Virus analyzer" window appears, freezes for few seconds, and then says that no menace was found. But it actually didn't analyze anything. 
I'm using trusty.

Comment: Is your virus database up to date? Could you please operate `clamscan` from the command line and add its output to the question? Learn how to use it in the terminal here: http://askubuntu.com/q/250290/367990

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm now running clamav from the terminal, it seems to work. It says I need to update it, but I'd love to find a .deb package or similar for that: I tried to compile it from source without success before.

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately I don't know much more about that, I simply use the command line version of the build from the repository...